# Load remote image URL with loadDataWithBaseURL method of WebView

Tags: android, html, string, android-webview

I need to load the HTML content which includes, remote image src.

So I wrote a string like below

```
String trl = "<html><body><a id=\"example1\"  href=\"http://example.com/android/images/4252054277_f0fa91e026.jpg\"><img alt=\"example1\" src=\"http://example.com/android/images/4252054277_f0fa91e026_m.jpg\" /></a></body></html>";
```

I then load with the below URL

```
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("", trl, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
```

It's showing the text i.e **"example-1"** instead of showing the image from the URL. I double check the location of images too. they are valid.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have changed the src url its working .

Comment: I am sorry, I just fixed this sometime ago. remember to post it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can be closed under: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers_.